# MySQL Workbench joined tables edit - Read Only

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mysql-workbench

I got the following query at MySQL Workbench

```
SELECT products_name,
    products_weight
FROM zen_products zp
JOIN zen_products_description pd ON zp.products_id = pd.products_id
```

Becuase the products_id are the same in both tables and these are the primary keys, how do I go about then to edit both tables from one query output. As it states at the moment: Read Only.

Comment: Possibly relevant MySQL Workbench bug for people who found this thread with a web search: [views' result grids are not editable](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83195). Note that this pertains to _views_, not joined tables, which meet all the other constraints required to be "[updatable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-updatability.html)" and can be modified with straight SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No workbench user, but in general in databases there's no "edit" command. It's a term workbench seems to have invented and it can mean two things:

1. Editing the table/database structure. In SQL this is done via the `ALTER TABLE ...` command.
2. Editing the data in one or more tables. In SQL this is done via the three commands `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT`.

Editing a table/database structure is done to only one table at a time. There's no joining allowed when doing this. That's why there's the "read only" note, if workbench means this with "editing". I'm assuming you mean to edit the data, especially updating it. An example would be

```
UPDATE zen_products zp
JOIN zen_products_description pd ON zp.products_id = pd.products_id
SET
zp.products_name = pd.another_column,
zp.products_weight = zp.products_weight + 1;
```

Note, that there are no restrictions on primary keys or anything, to update a table. You can join on any field and still update it. Given of course, you have the right to do so. Please execute this query:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR username@host;
```

to see if you have the rights to update the table.

Comment: Well MyPHP Admin & Workbench allows to edit the individual fields, however when the tables are joined together it not available as it can not track the primary key - which means it wont know which field to edit. Any suggestions, how to update columns quickly?